# Separating a single string into separate variables

Tags: c++, string, split

In my program I receive a string: `"09:07:38,50,100"`
(the numbers will be changing, only commas are consistent)

My desired output would be separating the string into 3 different variables for use in other things.

like so:

a = 09:07:38

b = 50

c = 100

Currently I tried splitting the string by separating it at commas, but I still lack the ability to put the data into different variables, or at least the knowledge on how to.

Here is my current code:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<sstream>

int main() {
    std::string my_str = "09:07:38,50,100";
    std::vector<std::string> result;

    std::stringstream s_stream(my_str); //create stringstream from the string
    
    while(s_stream.good()){
        std::string substr;
        getline(s_stream, substr, ','); //get first string delimited by comma
        result.push_back(substr);
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i<result.size(); i++){ //print all splitted strings
        std::cout << result.at(i) << std::endl; 
    }
    
}
```

Comment: what's the type for the variables you want the data stored in ? (ie a,b,c)

Comment: I want them stored as strings

std::string a = "";

std::string b = "";

std::string c = "";

Comment: Note that your reading loop suffers from the same problem as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Comment: `std::string a = result[0]` etc. Maybe check if `result.size() == 3` before that. You can also transform them into numbers, like `double a = std::stod(input)`.

Comment: looks to me like all you want is `std::string a = result[0];`

Answer (score 0):

The [stoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/) function is what you require.

```c
a = stoi(result.at(i));
std::cout << a;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think is a good idea to approach this kind of problem using regular expressions:

```
#include <string>
#include <boost\regex.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::string my_str = "09:07:38,50,100";

    std::string a,b,c;

    boost::regex regEx("(\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}),(\\d*),(\\d*)");

    if(boost::regex_match(my_str, regEx, boost::match_extra))
    {
        boost::smatch what;
        boost::regex_search(my_str, what, regEx);

        a = what[1];
        b = what[2];
        c = what[3];
    }

    std::cout<< "a = " << a << "\n";
    std::cout<< "b = " << b << "\n";
    std::cout<< "c = " << c;
}
```